# Ormlite RawRowMapper chokes on long field with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ormlite

I'm trying to use queryRaw with a RawRowMapper on MySQL.  It works great with string columns, but .mapRow() chokes on if I add a long field -- it attempts to convert the column name to numeric.

The [doc for getRawRowMapper](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#getRawRowMapper%28%29) says it's experimental and to provide feedback, but I am only an egg, so if anyone else has succeeded with this configuration, I'll try harder before bugging Gray with it.

My code as follows:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.LONG_STRING)
@Getter @Setter
private String formatted_message;

@DatabaseField(id=true)
@Getter @Setter
private long event_id;

public void getRowMapper() {
        RawRowMapper<DbLog> rowMapper = daol.getRawRowMapper();
        final String[] rowmap = { DbLog.EVENTID_FIELD, DbLog.MESSAGE_FIELD, DbLog.LEVEL_FIELD }; //
        try {
            rowMapper.mapRow( rowmap, rowmap );
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

It returns the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "event_id"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
at com.j256.ormlite.field.types.LongObjectType.parseDefaultString(LongObjectType.java:32)
at com.j256.ormlite.field.types.BaseDataType.resultStringToJava(BaseDataType.java:161)
at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.convertStringToJavaField(FieldType.java:671)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.RawRowMapperImpl.mapRow(RawRowMapperImpl.java:33)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working example.  It is an access class for the [Logback DbAppender's `logging_event` table](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html), which is an awfully nifty way to make Slf4j log to a database.  The SQL is complicated substantially by my need to filter logging_event rows by the presence or absence of specific MDC rows (they're like optional tags for log events) in the companion table `logging_event_property`.

The use of RawRowMapper, however, is perfectly standard.  The issue was my lack of comprehension:

1. You don't call `mapRow()` yourself.  It is called by `queryRaw`, [as is explained perfectly well in the docs.](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRaw%28java.lang.String,%20com.j256.ormlite.dao.RawRowMapper,%20java.lang.String...%29)
2. The mapper you get from `dao.getRawRowMapper()` will just work, even if you're not doing a `SELECT *`.  Trust it until you have a reason not to.

Anyhow, here's the working access classes, along with my funky double-join filtering.  Might be useful for anyone trying to use the DbAppender in an Ormlite project.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "logging_event")
public class DbLog {
    public static String EVENTID_FIELD = "event_id";
    public static String TIMESTAMP_FIELD = "timestmp";
    public static String MESSAGE_FIELD = "formatted_message";
    public static String LEVEL_FIELD = "level_string";

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private long timestmp;

    @DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.LONG_STRING)
    @Getter @Setter
    private String formatted_message;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private String logger_name;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private String level_string;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private String thread_name;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private byte reference_flag;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private String arg0;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private String arg1;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private String arg2;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private String arg3;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private String caller_filename;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private String caller_class;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private String caller_method;

    @DatabaseField
    @Getter @Setter
    private String caller_line;

    @DatabaseField(id=true)
    @Getter @Setter
    private long event_id;

    /** Gets server logs since timestamp.
     * Filters out logs which have NO MDC called "Client".
     * @param daol - Dao for DbLog.
     * @param timestamp - get only logs after this.
     * @param eventId - if not zero, filters out logs matching this event.
     * @return
     */

    public static GenericRawResults<DbLog> getServerLogsSince(Dao<DbLog, Long> daol, long timestamp, int eventId ) {
        try {
            // NB: This is not tested on SQLite.
            String mySqlQuery =  "SELECT ";
            mySqlQuery += "a.event_id, a.formatted_message, a.level_string "; 
            mySqlQuery += "FROM logging_event a ";
            mySqlQuery += "LEFT JOIN logging_event_property b ";
            mySqlQuery += "ON ( a.event_id = b.event_id ";
            mySqlQuery += "    and b.mapped_key = 'Event'   ";
            if( eventId != 0) { 
                mySqlQuery += "      and b.mapped_value = ? ";
            }
            mySqlQuery += ") ";
            mySqlQuery += "LEFT JOIN logging_event_property c ";
            mySqlQuery += "ON ( a.event_id = c.event_id AND c.mapped_key = 'Client') ";
            mySqlQuery += "WHERE a.timestmp > ? ";
            mySqlQuery += "and c.event_id is null ";

            RawRowMapper<DbLog> rowMapper = daol.getRawRowMapper();

            String evStr = Long.toString(db.getEvent().getId());
            String timeStr = Long.toString(timestamp);
            GenericRawResults<DbLog> results;
            if( eventId == 0)
                results = daol.queryRaw(mySqlQuery, rowMapper, timeStr);
            else 
                results = daol.queryRaw(mySqlQuery, rowMapper, evStr, timeStr);


            return results;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Exception {}",Helpers.stackTraceInfo(e,DbLog.class));
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "logging_event_property")
public class DbLogProp {
    public static String EVENTID_FIELD = "event_id";
    public static String MAPPEDKEY_FIELD = "mapped_key";
    public static String MAPPEDVALUE_FIELD = "mapped_value";

    @DatabaseField(columnName="event_id", foreign=true)
    @Getter @Setter
    //private Long event_id;
    DbLog event;

    @DatabaseField(columnName="mapped_key")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String mappedKey;

    @DatabaseField(columnName="mapped_value")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String mappedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to use queryRaw with a RawRowMapper on MySQL. It works great with string columns, but .mapRow() chokes on if I add a long field -- it attempts to convert the column name to numeric.

`getRawRowMapper()` has been around a while and really isn't experimental.  I'll change the comments.

I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen but ORMLite is trying to convert the `EVENTID_FIELD` which is a string into a `long`.  The [`mapRow(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/RawRowMapper.html#mapRow(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[])) definition is:

```
T mapRow(String[] columnNames, String[] resultColumns) throws SQLException
```

and you are trying to pass in the `rowmap` as the `resultColumns`.  I assume that the first result column is supposed to be a long and it is trying to do a 
`Long.parseLong("event_id")` which throws.

If you provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish, I can see if I can help.

Comment: Thanks Gray, "It's not experimental anymore" combined with "What are you trying to do" were just the hints I needed.   Basically I just didn't believe that my situation was as simple as the examples I found, and went looking to make it complicated.  Working code posted, but it's not worth reading -- the use of `RawRowMapper` is perfectly standard.